# Parallelism and Arrays? a Runtime defined amount of calculations to a runtime defined sub group of elements

Tags: c#, performance, linq, asynchronous

I have an undefined amount of elements (less than a long size) to which I have to perform a runtime amount of calculations to some of them (the operations to do and to which element positions is something received as an argument).

The arguments then, the number of positions and a List Instructions (add this to the positions going from X to Y, substract this to the positions from P to Q)

The solution I had was:

1. Fill `List<long> Output` with 0s according to the length received by args;
2. `long output[] = Output.ToArray();`
3. `Instructions.ForEach(op => DoOperations(op));`
   (Where `op` had from what position to what position do I have to do which calculation with what numbers)
4. A `for` doing calculations on each of the filtered positions of `output[]` .

   Now the thing is the time constraint makes this all not viable, so I need an async/WhenAll into action, but also I need all of them to share the `output` so they can all operate on it, it's not a problem which operation gets solved first. And there's no `ref` or `out` parameters in Async.

What is the most efficient and clean way to do this?

@Edit to show how parallel is working:

```
static long arrayManipulation(int n, int[][] queries) 
    {
        long[] operate;
        for(long i=0;i<n;i++) 
            lOperate.Add(0);

        operate = lOperate.ToArray();
        List<int[]> lQueries = new List<int[]>(queries.ToList<int[]>());    
        Parallel.ForEach(lQueries, op=>
        {
            Parallel.For(op[0]-1, op[1], i=> (operate[i]+= (long)op[2]));
        });
        return operate.Max();
    }
```

Comment: This sounds like a programming challenge and I believe the trick is to not actually have all the values, but instead keep track of subsets.  So if it's say 100 values and you're told to add 1 to positions 5 to 9 all you need is to store 0-4 is 0, 5-9 is 1, and 10-99 is 0.  And just keep partitioning as you do more operations.

Comment: Unless you're actually calling stuff outside your code you can await (file acces, http call etc) wouldn't you be better off with `Parallel.ForEach`?

Comment: Further I don't think you can parallelize this as I would assume the operations have to been done in order to get the correct results.

Comment: @Knoop, this could be a solution: * it's not a problem which operation gets solved first* as all the operations are addition/substraction in isolation of the position, with no race condition inconveniences.

Comment: `async`/`WhenAll` is for I/O operations, like making web requests or querying a database or a filesystem. It seems that you have CPU-bound operations instead, so what you really need is [parallelism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/), not asynchrony.

Comment: @Knoop Parallel did not cut it, still takes too long. BTW, juharr it is a challenge.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes, you are right, I adjusted the title accordingly, but it still seems not to be the most efficient solution. What Am I missing?

Comment: To be honest I think you're looking at the problem the wrong way. But first let me note that there is a lot of highly inefficiënt code before you even begin your calculations. For example you can just do this: `var operate = new long[n];` this will already give you an array of length `n` with all values set to 0. Also the queries you could operate directly on `queries`. That said I would not think of it as additions to single elements but as ranges of a height. Then create a 'skyline' and check where it's the highest.

Comment: How do you know whether to add or subtract?

Comment: @NetMage I always add, sometimes I add a negative number

Answer (score 1):

Without any information on the scale of the issue, it is hard to attempt to optmize, but some quick tests show that running the add operations in parallel is not worth it. There is some overhead to setting up the `Parallel.For` and calling the lambda method, and that swamps the time to just use a basic `for` loop and addition.

OTOH, using an outside `Parallel.For` to step through the operations is worthwhile (on a multi-core CPU at least) running four times faster on my computer. Unrolling the inner loops a few times to batch the operations does not seem to provide an advantage at 2x and 4x. Using the standard LINQ `Max` operator is only 0.2% of the total time, so attempting to track the max during the operations does not seem worthwhile.

So my suggestion is:

```
Parallel.For(0, operations.Length, j1 => {
    var op = operations[j1];
    for (int j2 = op[0]; j2 < op[1]; ++j2)
        operate[j2] += op[2];
});
var ans = operate.Max();
```